# LinqToWiki C# Cannot retrieve imageinfo in Wikipedia

Tags: c#, wikipedia-api, linq-to-wiki

I'm querying Wikipedia using LinqToWiki library for c#.
In particular I want to retrieve the full image url that points to wiki page File:Cinnamomum_verum.jpg

Using the official Media Wiki API the request is: http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&titles=File:Cinnamomum_verum.jpg

As you can see just by entering in a browser, the xml response contains imageinfo structure, in particular the url .

I cannot retrieve this information using LinqToWiki.

I use the following code:

```
var c = wiki.CreateTitlesSource("File:Cinnamomum_verum.jpg");

var source = pages
                .Select(
                    p =>
                    PageResult.Create(
                        p.info,
                        p.imageinfo()
                            .Select(i => new { i.comment }).ToEnumerable())
                ).ToEnumerable();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in item.Data)
                {
                    //retrieve all urls detected
                }
            }
```

The first foreach statement correctly retrieves one element (the page), but the inner one return none.
Anybody encountered the same problem? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything, I just didn't expect that pages that don't actually exist (on the wiki you're using) could have useful data. I'll try to fix this soon, but as a temporary workaround, you could query http://commons.wikimedia.org directly for images from there.

**EDIT:** I have updated LinqToWiki, the new version should handle `imageinfo` correctly.